# Unexpectedly found Nil unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am aware that there are many other questions like this however I assure you this is not a duplicate as far as I can tell.  As you can see in the code below I have not marked any values as Optional however I keep getting this error.  It crashes when I run the snapNext value highlighting the

```
 viewMap.camera = newLocation
```

Here is the full code below, I have the viewMap linked to just a regular UIView

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(33.600727, longitude: -117.900840, zoom: 16.9)
@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    viewMap.camera = camera
    viewMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
    viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true


    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.600727, -117.900840)
    marker.title = "Newport Beach"
    marker.snippet = "California"
    marker.map = viewMap

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func snapNext(sender: AnyObject) {
    let newLocation = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(33.622578, longitude: -117.911099, zoom: 16.9)
    viewMap.camera = newLocation

   }
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Make sure viewMap is connected to your xib or storyboard

Comment: just confirmed that it was

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the start of the `snapNext` function and verify that `viewMap` isn't nil.

Comment: that could be only reason or either somehow you had make it nil in runtime

Comment: @Paulw11 it is nil within the function however I don't understand when it becomes nil as it has a value when I set another breakpoint at the end of my viewdidload()

Comment: How are you instantiating the instance of the view controller that is running this function?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is simply the default controller that is with a single view project, so is the storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the line:

```
viewMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
```

Here you are setting the map to a new anonymous object and because the map property is weak it will be set to `nil` automatically as soon as the anonymous object goes out of scope (i.e. when `viewDidLoad` completes).
Either you want to create the object in the storyboard; in which case leave it as a weak outlet, or you just want it as a 'normal' property; in which case remove the `weak` and `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewControllerGMSMapViewDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var camera:GMSCameraPosition!

@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(33.600727, longitude: -117.900840, zoom: 16.9)

    viewMap.camera = camera
    viewMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
    viewMap.delegate=self

    viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true


    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.600727, -117.900840)
    marker.title = "Newport Beach"
    marker.snippet = "California"
    marker.map = viewMap

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func snapNext(sender: AnyObject) {
    camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(33.622578, longitude: -117.911099, zoom: 16.9)
    viewMap.camera = camera

   }
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to add an "@IBAction" into the viewDidLoad()? It gives me an error and tells me to remove the "@IBAction" prefix form the function

Answer (score 0):

As you've already pointed out the `viewMap` is nil. Why it's getting released, I do not know (Need more info to know that). But I know that you can prevent it by removing the `weak` keyword.

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
```

However, this might lead to leaks if you have retain cycles between your viewMap and your view controller.